# How to collapse UITableView header as you scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The functionality I am trying to achieve is shown in Twitter [here](https://michiganlabs.com/assets/images/posts/twitter_demo.cb5f0966.gif).

I have been looking at several resources online including this [article](https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/) by Michigan Labs which is very useful in getting the collapsing animation by using constraints on a header view that is above the `UITableView`

The problem I see with this approach is that since it is not technically part of the `UITableView`, the header will not be responding to Up/Down scroll gestures. However, when I download the Twitter app, the header does respond to touch. How do I make the header sensitive to touch gestures as well?

Summary: I want to duplicate that middle section where it shows the profile picture, followers, buttons, and segmented control that collapses until only the segmented control is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll view exposes it's gesture handler so you can just add it to your view and it should work.

```
view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollView.panGestureRecognizer)
```

Also, since the header seems to be inside the table view, you can clear the `userInteractionEnabled` for the header view, and it will send the gestures to the underlying view instead.

Edit:
Since the gesture only can belong to a single view at a time I suggest this method instead. Override the `hittest` lower level method on UIView to steer events to the correct view. Implement this on your header view, and always return the table view. You can add the table view as a property on the header view, and set it in `viewDidLoad`.

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    if self.pointInside(point, withEvent: event)
        return self.tableView
    return nil;
 }
```

(Objective-C version below)

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if ([self pointInside:point withEvent:event])
        return _nextView;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: No. But in any case adding the gesture handler to the header view works. I have used it several times, and all sub-classes of UIScrollView can use this pattern. Basically you can set up a completely separate UIView and use as a scrolling pad for your scroll view / table view.

Comment: So I implemented it and it seems like if I add the GestureRecognizer to the the view, the TableView will lose the gesture recognizer. Anyway for both views to accept scrolling?

Comment: Did you try to turn off userInteractionEnabled for the header view? Otherwise you can also put a transparent view over the entire table view, including over the header that has the gesture recognizer.

Comment: I'll give the transparent view a shot. I read some docs and it seems there can only be a 1 to 1 view to gesture recognizer.

Comment: You are right, it can only be attached to one view, although one view can have several recognizers.

Comment: Seems like the transparent view will not work since the tableview and any buttons become untappable. I can't disable userInteractionEnabled for the transparent view as it will not respond to pan gestures. I may need to add the view inside the TableView

Comment: Please try set the userInteractionEnabled to false on the header. I think it will work regardless of parent/child relationship of the view.

Comment: I did it, but the header will not respond even if there is a gesture recognizer added.

Comment: If you set userInteractionEnabled to false it will let gestures through to views below, so in that case it shouldn’t have a gesture recognizer. Only do one or the other. But disabling user interaction if there is nothing below to catch it then it won’t work anyway.

Comment: right. So it sounds like I need to add the header to the UITableView and disable user interaction.

Comment: I just tried putting a UIView partly overlapping a table view, not embedding it, just sharing the same parent view as the table view, and with user interaction turned off on the UIView the table view scrolls when it pan inside the UIView part that overlaps the table view.

Comment: I updated with another solution that will work better. I tried this, and it will continue to accept scrolling in the table view, and also _relay_ scrolling from another view.

Comment: interesting. but if I had buttons in the header view, I am assuming it would get swallowed up by overriding the hit test?

Comment: Not necessarily. In the hitTest: you can call the super and check it's return value first. If it returns self then you return _nextView, otherwise it has returned a sub-view (or sub-sub-view etc), so return what you got instead.